# How to dynamically execute C or C++ code in iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, c, dynamic, execute

I have an `NSString` containing C or C++ code in iOS, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "Hello World"  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I execute it dynamically in Objective-C and get an `NSString` as answer?

Comment: You will need to embed your own C/C++ interpreter/compiler in your app. Good luck.

Comment: C++ is a compiled language, so there is no interpreter that you can feed code to at runtime. You'll need to put a compiler or interpreter on the system executing your code.